# Grunt.js dependency management

Tags: dependencies, gruntjs, recompile

Is there a way to specify file dependencies in Grunt? I.e. if I have:

```
global/page.jade
project/index.jade -- includes global/page.jade
project/about.jade -- includes global/page.jade
project/test.jade
```

and I change `global/page.jade` then I would like to get `project/index|about.jade` recompiled. I checked out the plugins but couldn't find anything that would provide that functionality.

Comment: What task are you using?

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen I am using `grunt-contrib-jade` and having the same problem. my `gruntfile` here: https://gist.github.com/Grawl/11396423

Comment: I asked a question at `grunt-cotrib-jade` repo and there is no answers yet. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade/issues/100

Comment: Don't rely on jade and try grunt-contrib-watch todo recompile?

Comment: On line 63 try to change `'newer:jade'` to `'jade'`, this should compile all jade templates, not just the changed one.

Comment: Never! `newer` is highly required for my projects.

Comment: I think you should restate the question: "How to recompile jade dependencies using grunt-newer" if you require newer. Using watch achieves your current stated aims, and the `newer` answer is incomplete…

Comment: @memeLab okay I will ask it

Comment: Okay I asked about this problem at `newer` repo Issues https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer/issues/44

Answer (score 5):

[grunt watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) use in your gruntfile.js in following way

```
...

  watch: {
    scripts: {
      files: 'src/**/*',
      tasks: ['buildDevelopment'],
      options: {
        interrupt: true,
      },
    }

grunt.registerTask('buildDevelopment', ['clean'
                        ,'jade'
                        ,'copy:development'
                        ,'bowercopy:development'
                        ]);

...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest enhancing Atillas solution. Rebuilding all templates on every change isn't optimal and will piss you off on large projects.

#### Here's what should help:

#### *Use newer plugin to process only changed files*

**Install:** npm install grunt-newer --save-dev
**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-newer#optionsoverride
**Usage:**

- prefix tasks with newer:
- add grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer'); to gruntfile
- use override option to check includes (the magic you're looking for)

`newer: {
        options: {
            override: function (detail, include) {
                if (detail.task === 'jade') {
                    checkForModifiedImports(detail.path, detail.time, include);
                } else {
                    include(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }`

#### *Use watch to detect file changes*

**Install:** npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch
**Usage:**

- add grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch'); to gruntfile
- task can look like something like this

`watch: {
        scripts: {
            files: '**/*.jade',
            tasks: ['newer:jade'],
            options: {
                interrupt: true
            },
        },
    }`

Comment: I've got `Fatal error: checkForModifiedImports is not defined` on this.
Used [`gruntfile.coffee`](https://gist.github.com/Grawl/0eef67b20a40ec97ace1)

Comment: looks like `checkForModifiedImports()` is a user defined function - there is no definition in the newer, jade, or less projects (the newer readme cites less). I'd love to see an example!

Comment: Okay I asked about this problem at `newer` repo Issues https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer/issues/44

Comment: You have to write your own function for that. I will post example soon.

Comment: I just find a working solution into someone's [gruntfile.coffee#105](https://github.com/nwalton3/grunt-starter/blob/6992093e3513d67b910fbba81b30132fd0f6792e/Gruntfile.coffee#L105) on Github. it's simple as 1,2,3: `if detail.task is 'jade` then `include true`. and it works.